# How to correctly set Flutter Switch Widget theme

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to theme flutter's switch widget within the ThemeData constructor, and I'm having some difficulty with defining the Switch theme. When I use this for the `switchTheme` property:

```dart
    switchTheme: SwitchThemeData(
      thumbColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(primary),
    ),
```

It looks like this:

[image]

When I enter this:

```dart
    switchTheme: SwitchThemeData(
      thumbColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(primary),
      trackColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(primary),
    ),
```

It looks like this:

[image]

What I expect/want is for the track of the switch to be grayed out when off and the thumb orange then the track and thumb to be orange when on. Is there some kind of way we're supposed to use the MaterialStateProperty class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out after reading the documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialStateProperty-class.html)

```dart
    switchTheme: SwitchThemeData(
        thumbColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(primary),
        trackColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) =>
            states.contains(MaterialState.selected) ? primary : null)),
```